# Docker container not able to ping my remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Basically i have machine remotely that have list of jars hold .Once you go to that IP address you can download the jars.

Now coming to the problem i went to the docker container to check whether my site is available to that docker.by terminal command "ping jarholder.xxxxx.com"

it comes up error unknown host jarholder.xxxxx.com

if i come out docker container and if i do the same command "ping jarholder.vishnu.com" in same ubuntu local machine terminal i am able to exchange packets.

can anyone help me what can i do to make docker to ping my site.

Comment: Can you ping any external sites? Is it a custom URL (do you need to add some DNS resolution / host edits in order to resolve the domain?)

Comment: No actually i am not able to ping the external sites as well.

Comment: What network settings are you using for your container? You can find this in the output of `docker inspect $container_name`